# Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_grant: Bad Request, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I got stranger problem when deploy my ruby on rails app on docker

When I run `localhost` all work perfectly, but when `deploy on docker` I got this error.

I using few days for resolving this but unsuccessful, can anyone help me resolved this problem?

This is log i got:

```sh
E, [2021-10-14T18:13:18.970657 #1] ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, invalid_grant: Bad Request
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

This is docker file

```
FROM ruby:2.6.2-alpine
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN apk add --update npm tzdata openssl git openssh zlib-dev libxml2-dev redis \
    libxslt-dev yaml-dev bash ruby-dev build-base linux-headers && \
    npm install -g bower && \
    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries && \
    bundle install --without development test --no-deployment --binstubs && \
    bundle clean && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    mkdir -p /home/rails/eros/tmp/pids && \
    touch /home/rails/eros/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
ADD . /home/rails/eros
WORKDIR /home/rails/eros
RUN redis-server & \
    bundle exec rake bower:install['--allow-root'] && \
    bundle exec rake assets:precompile
ENV RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES true
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT true
CMD bundle exec rake assets:precompile && bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

My gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0.5'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.0.2'

# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.0.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem "rack_session_access"
  gem 'pry-rails'
  # gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
  # gem 'debase'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
gem 'whenever', '~> 0.9.4', :require => false

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

#
gem 'mongoid', '6.0.0.rc0'

# Notifier Slack
gem 'slack-notifier'

gem 'bson_ext', '1.5.1'

gem 'rails_param', '0.9.0'

gem 'dotenv-rails', '2.0.1'

gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.58.2', require: false

gem 'bower-rails', '~> 0.10.0'

gem "font-awesome-rails"

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'

gem 'haml-rails', '~> 0.9.0'

gem 'will_paginate_mongoid', '~> 2.0.1'

gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'shoryuken'
gem 'rufus-scheduler'


gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'

gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17.47'

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano',         require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rvm',     require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails',   require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma',   require: false
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
  gem 'capistrano-shoryuken'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.48.1'
  gem 'minitest-rails'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
end

#load environment variables from .env into ENV in development.
gem "figaro"

# fix paginate rails 5
# gem 'kaminari', github: "amatsuda/kaminari", branch: '0-17-stable'
gem 'resque'
gem 'resque-web', require: 'resque_web'
gem 'redis', '~>3.2'
gem 'highcharts-rails', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.9'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-rails_csrf_protection', '~> 1.0'
# gem 'lograge', '~> 0.4.1'
gem 'request_store', '~> 1.3.1'
gem 'rest-client', '~> 2.0.0.rc2'
gem 'jsonapi-resources'
#Do some browser detection with Ruby. Includes ActionController integration.

gem 'browser'

gem 'gelf'
gem 'lograge'
# Sentry-raven
gem 'sentry-raven'
gem 'aws-sdk-sqs'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
gem 'rubyzip', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'axlsx', '2.1.0.pre'
gem 'axlsx_rails'

#queue
gem 'bunny', '>= 2.7.0'
gem 'colorize'

gem 'pureapi', '~> 0.5.1'
gem 'redis-rails'

gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-cron'
gem 'sinatra', :require => false
gem 'bitly', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'

gem 'chart-js-rails'
```

```
Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.17.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Using rake 13.0.6
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
Using i18n 1.8.10
Using minitest 5.14.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.9
Using activesupport 5.0.7.1
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.6.1
Using racc 1.5.2
Using nokogiri 1.12.5 (x86_64-linux)
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.12.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.2
Using actionview 5.0.7.1
Using rack 2.2.3
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 5.0.7.1
Using nio4r 2.3.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using actioncable 5.0.7.1
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 5.0.7.1
Using mini_mime 1.0.1
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailer 5.0.7.1
Using activemodel 5.0.7.1
Using arel 7.1.4
Using activerecord 5.0.7.1
Using public_suffix 3.0.3
Using addressable 2.6.0
Using net-ssh 5.1.0
Using net-scp 1.2.1
Using sshkit 1.18.2
Using airbrussh 1.3.1
Using amq-protocol 2.3.0
Using ansi 1.5.0
Using ast 2.4.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using autoprefixer-rails 9.4.10
Using aws-eventstream 1.0.1
Using aws-partitions 1.141.0
Using aws-sigv4 1.0.3
Using jmespath 1.4.0
Using aws-sdk-core 3.46.2
Using aws-sdk-kms 1.13.0
Using aws-sdk-s3 1.30.1
Using aws-sdk-sqs 1.10.0
Using htmlentities 4.3.4
Using rubyzip 1.1.7
Using axlsx 2.1.0.pre
Using axlsx_rails 0.5.2
Using bcrypt 3.1.16
Using bindex 0.5.0
Using mime-types-data 3.2018.0812
Using mime-types 3.2.2
Using multi_xml 0.6.0
Using httparty 0.16.4
Using multi_json 1.15.0
Using multipart-post 2.1.1
Using faraday 0.17.4
Using jwt 2.3.0
Using oauth2 1.4.7
Using bitly 1.1.2
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using ffi 1.10.0
Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.7.3
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
Using method_source 0.9.2
Using thor 0.20.3
Using railties 5.0.7.1
Using momentjs-rails 2.20.1
Using bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails 4.17.47
Using bower-rails 0.10.0
Using browser 2.5.3
Using bson 4.4.2
Using bson_ext 1.5.1
Using bundler 1.17.2
Using bunny 2.14.1
Using byebug 11.0.0
Using capistrano 3.11.0
Using capistrano-bundler 1.5.0
Using capistrano-rails 1.4.0
Using capistrano-rvm 0.1.2
Using capistrano-shoryuken 0.1.5
Using puma 3.12.0
Using capistrano3-puma 3.1.1
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using capybara 2.18.0
Using chart-js-rails 0.1.6
Using childprocess 0.9.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using tilt 2.0.9
Using sass-rails 5.0.7
Using chosen-rails 1.8.7
Using chronic 0.10.2
Using cliver 0.3.2
Using coderay 1.1.2
Using colorize 0.8.1
Using commonjs 0.2.7
Using connection_pool 2.2.2
Using safe_yaml 1.0.5
Using crack 0.4.3
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using responders 3.0.1
Using warden 1.2.9
Using devise 4.8.0
Using unf_ext 0.0.7.5
Using unf 0.1.4
Using domain_name 0.5.20180417
Using dotenv 2.0.1
Using dotenv-rails 2.0.1
Using et-orbi 1.1.7
Using figaro 1.1.1
Using font-awesome-rails 4.7.0.4
Using sassc 2.0.1
Using font-awesome-sass 5.6.1
Using raabro 1.1.6
Using fugit 1.1.8
Using json 2.2.0
Using gelf 3.1.0
Using haml 4.0.7
Using sexp_processor 4.11.0
Using ruby_parser 3.12.0
Using html2haml 2.2.0
Using haml-rails 0.9.0
Using hashdiff 0.3.8
Using hashie 4.1.0
Using highcharts-rails 4.2.7
Using http-cookie 1.0.3
Using jaro_winkler 1.5.2
Using jbuilder 2.8.0
Using jquery-rails 4.3.3
Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Using turbolinks 5.0.1
Using jquery-turbolinks 2.0.2
Using jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5
Using jsonapi-resources 0.9.5
Using less 2.6.0
Using less-rails 2.8.0
Using listen 3.0.8
Using request_store 1.3.2
Using lograge 0.10.0
Using minitest-capybara 0.8.2
Using minitest-metadata 0.6.0
Using minitest-rails 3.0.0
Using minitest-rails-capybara 3.0.1
Using ruby-progressbar 1.10.0
Using minitest-reporters 1.3.6
Using mongo 2.7.1
Using mongoid 6.0.0.rc0
Using mono_logger 1.1.0
Using mustermann 1.0.3
Using netrc 0.11.0
Using rack-protection 2.0.5
Using omniauth 2.0.4
Using omniauth-oauth2 1.7.1
Using omniauth-google-oauth2 1.0.0
Using omniauth-rails_csrf_protection 1.0.0
Using parallel 1.14.0
Using parser 2.6.0.0
Using poltergeist 1.18.1
Using powerpack 0.1.2
Using pry 0.12.2
Using pry-rails 0.3.9
Using pureapi 0.5.1
Using rack-cors 1.0.2
Using rack-mini-profiler 1.0.2
Using rack_session_access 0.2.0
Using rails 5.0.7.1
Using rails-controller-testing 1.0.4
Using rails_param 0.9.0
Using rainbow 3.0.0
Using redis 3.3.5
Using redis-store 1.6.0
Using redis-rack 2.0.5
Using redis-actionpack 5.0.2
Using redis-activesupport 5.0.7
Using redis-namespace 1.6.0
Using redis-rails 5.0.2
Using sinatra 2.0.5
Using vegas 0.1.11
Using resque 2.0.0
Using twitter-bootstrap-rails 4.0.0
Using resque-web 0.0.12
Using rest-client 2.0.2
Using unicode-display_width 1.4.1
Using rubocop 0.58.2
Using rufus-scheduler 3.5.2
Using websocket 1.2.8
Using selenium-webdriver 2.48.1
Using sentry-raven 2.9.0
Using shoryuken 4.0.3
Using sidekiq 5.2.5
Using sidekiq-cron 1.1.0
Using slack-notifier 2.3.2
Using spring 2.0.2
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using uglifier 4.1.20
Using web-console 3.7.0
Using webmock 3.5.1
Using whenever 0.9.7
Using will_paginate 3.1.6
Using will_paginate_mongoid 2.0.1
```

This is config in devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'], {
    :scope => "email, profile",
    :prompt => "select_account",
    :image_aspect_ratio => "square",
    :image_size => 50,
  }
```

This my OmniauthCallbacksController

```
class Staffs::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  skip_before_action :auth_staff

  OMNIAUTH = 'omniauth.auth'
  GOOGLE = 'Google'
  OMNIAUTH_SUCCESS = 'devise.omniauth_callbacks.success'
  OMNIAUTH_FAILURE = 'devise.omniauth_callbacks.failure'
  MSG_EMAIL_NOT_OMNIAUTH = 'email chưa được xác thực'

  def google_oauth2
      # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
      @staff = Staff.from_omniauth(request.env[OMNIAUTH])
      puts "===================================>: #{@staff.to_json}"
      unless @staff.blank?
        flash[:notice] = I18n.t OMNIAUTH_SUCCESS, :kind => GOOGLE
        sign_in_and_redirect @staff, :event => :authentication
      else
        session["devise.google_data"] = request.env[OMNIAUTH].except('extra')
        @staff = Staff.create_or_sync_account_edumall(request.env[OMNIAUTH])
        unless @staff.blank?
          sign_in_and_redirect @staff, :event => :authentication
        else
          flash[:notice] = I18n.t OMNIAUTH_FAILURE, {:kind => GOOGLE, :reason => MSG_EMAIL_NOT_OMNIAUTH}
          redirect_to new_staff_session_path
        end
      end
  end
```